# Django App - Getting Initial Rows into Database

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a Django application and I have a few rows that I want to be in the application at the beginning of time. An example is a System Settings table that has some settings - they should be setup with any db instance that is constructed.

In the past, I had handled this by making an migration script manually that inserted the records. However, when I run my tests and the database is created and deleted, these scripts are not run again and the database is empty. The tests assume the that the migrations only have schema migrations, so that they don't need to run them again, but that is not the case. This has led me to think that maybe my migrations shouldn't be data migrations and I should rethink the process? I am not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe use fixtures in your tests for initial data for models.

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/initial-data/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I think I will still run into the same problem, though. Even with this method, all data will be deleted after each test, right?

Comment: Uhmm, as I see it, you are removing the database. In the past you said you handled it with scripts. Well the closest thing I know in django are the fixtures. Instead using scripts you could load the fixtures in your database creation task test.

Comment: That way you will always have the system settings fixture loaded in the DB after the DB has been created through the test task.

Comment: It looks like the fixtures are loaded through a command line call, so I am not sure how I would do that inside of a test.

Comment: How do you run your tests actually?

Comment: In my projects, we use an initial data fixture that populates data when performing migrate. This persists through tests. See the note here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#fixture-loading

Comment: The normal way. I have a test suite for functional tests with selenium and one for unit tests. Then I call the tests from the command line with the `test` command.

Comment: Ahhhh - thank you Mark. I didn't see that section about testing. I think that will be the answer.

Comment: What I meant is in case you were using Django test you can easily integrate your fixtures there. But in case you are using fabric or some python external script for testing you have to provide it manually to your test scripts.